# Crash in Fragment using view binding and live data observer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, android-viewbinding

This is my implementation:

```
class SampleFragment : Fragment()
{
    private val viewModel by sharedViewModel<MyViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View =
            FragmentSampleBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
                myButton.setOnClickListener { viewModel.foo() }

                viewModel.statusLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                    titleTextView.text = it.status.title
                    myButton.text = it.status.button_title
                })
            }.root
}
```

In rare occations, this crash happens:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.example.fragments.SampleFragment$onCreateView$1$2.onChanged (SampleFragment.kt:2)
  at com.example.fragments.SampleFragment$onCreateView$1$2.onChanged (SampleFragment.kt:1)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify (LiveData.java:6)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue (LiveData.java:5)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged (LiveData.java:10)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged (LiveData.java:3)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent (LifecycleRegistry.java:3)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass (LifecycleRegistry.java:9)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync (LifecycleRegistry.java:9)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState (LifecycleRegistry.java:5)
  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent (LifecycleRegistry.java:2)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent (FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.java:1)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart (Fragment.java:9)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start (FragmentStateManager.java:3)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:28)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:69)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManager.java:4)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:75)
  at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps (BackStackRecord.java:28)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps (FragmentManager.java:6)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:14)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java:10)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:4)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run (FragmentManager.java:1)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6823)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1563)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

One idea is that this happens when the view is destroyed before the `observe()` subscription has ended.

I dug into the fragment code and found this in FragmentManager:

```
private void destroyFragmentView(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
    fragment.performDestroyView();
    mLifecycleCallbacksDispatcher.dispatchOnFragmentViewDestroyed(fragment, false);
    fragment.mContainer = null;
    fragment.mView = null;
    // Set here to ensure that Observers are called after
    // the Fragment's view is set to null
    fragment.mViewLifecycleOwner = null;
    fragment.mViewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.setValue(null);
    fragment.mInLayout = false;
}
```

The `viewLifecycleOwner` actually is destroyed after the view has been destroyed. But since this function is non-suspendable, there should be no way of interleaving from the main thread.

Is my assumption correct?

I further found that the `viewLifecycleOwner` can live long if there is an exit transition (FragmentManager#moveToState() Lines 1261+):

```
// If a fragment has an exit animation (or transition), do not destroy
// its view immediately and set the state after animating
if (mExitAnimationCancellationSignals.get(f) == null) {
    destroyFragmentView(f);
} else {
    f.setStateAfterAnimating(newState);
}
```

However this would also delay the destruction of the view.

Do you have any ideas how the crash happens?
(I left the Koin injection of `sharedViewModel` in the sample in case this could be the source of a problem.)

Comment: Move your observer registration code to `onViewCreated`. I think Issue is if your livedata already has a value ready it immediately triggers the observer which tries to access the view but it cannot succeed because `onCreateView` haven't returned fragments view yet.

Comment: So what's actually null? Is it `it`, `it.status`? Because `titleTextView` and `myButton`, assuming they are part of the Binding you've inflated, cannot be null.

Comment: @Pawel I know this was a requirement when using kotlinx synthetic. 
When using view binding I can access the root view via the binding before it is even set as root view, right? Do you have a source generally recommending observers being registered in `onViewCreated()`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes, `titleTextView` and `myButton` are part of the binding. 
Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the crash and the stack trace is all the information I have.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at `statusLiveData` and every place that sets a value on that `LiveData`. You haven't included that code, so we can't help check whether `it` or `it.status` is ever null.